# Do minidump files contain the timestamp of the crash?

Tags: minidump, postmortem-debugging

The MiscInfoStream in a minidump file contains the process create time. I'd like to find out how long the process has been running for before the crash. Does a minidump file contain the exception timestamp anywhere?

WinDbg on this dump file displays the following, which implies that it's in there somewhere...

```
Debug session time: Tue Dec 29 15:49:20.000 2009 (GMT+0)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:33:03.000
```

(DumpChk displays the same information, at the end of the list of streams)

Note that today's Mar 15, so this is almost certainly the timestamp of the crash. I'd like a programmatic way to retrieve that value and the "Process Uptime" value.

I found the `MINIDUMP_MISC_INFO_3` structure, which contains some timezone information, but it doesn't seem to contain the exception time.

Some dump files appear to have a ThreadInfoListStream, which contains the timestamps for each thread in the process, but this isn't included in the minidumps that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values for the crash time and the process up time using the dbgeng api.  See the Windbg sdk directory for the dumpstk sample - you can modify it to get at this information.

My code below assumes you've added a new query interface for the system objects 2 interface into a new global g_SysObjects.

```
IDebugSystemObjects2* g_SysObjects;
```

and changed g_Control from IDebugControl to IDebugControl2.

```
#include <time.h>
void DumpUpTimeAndCrashTime()
{
    ULONG upTime = 0;

    g_SysObjects->GetCurrentProcessUpTime(&upTime);
    int days = upTime / (60*60*24);
    int hours = (upTime % (60*60*24)) / (60*60);
    int minutes = (upTime % (60*60))/60;
    int seconds = upTime % 60;
    printf("Process uptime %d days %02d:%02d:%02d.000\n", 
            days, hours, minutes, seconds);

    ULONG crashTime = 0;
    g_Control->GetCurrentTimeDate(&crashTime);
    time_t ct = crashTime;
    printf( "Crash time and date: %s", _ctime64( &ct ) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the time of the exception is stored anywhere in the minidump file. The exception structure certainly does not contain this info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680367%28VS.85%29.aspx

The misc info struct does contain the process start time, but not the exception time:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680389%28VS.85%29.aspx

You can see all the possible contents of a minidump here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx